# R: difference between apply(object, 1, function(x) sum(x-a)/b) and rowsums((object-a)/b)

Tags: r, floating-accuracy

I'm new to R and am struggling with the apply function. It is really slow to execute and I was trying to optimize some code I received.

I am trying to do some matrix operations (element-wise multiplication and division on ~10^6 element matrices) then sum the rows of the resulting matrix. I found the fantastic library `Rfast` and it executes what I thought was the same code in about 1/30 the time, but I am getting systematic differences between my 'optimized' answer and the previous answer.

The original code was something along the lines of

```
ans <- apply(object, 1, function(x) sum((x - a) / b))
```

and my code is

```
ans = Rfast:::rowsums((object-a)/b)
```

I'm not sure if it's because one of the methods is throwing away precision or making rounding errors - any thoughts?

**Edit**

Trying to reproduce the error is pretty hard...

I have been able to isolate the discrepancy to when I divide by my vector `b` with entries each ~ 3000 (i.e. `[3016.460436, 3021.210321, 3033.3303219]`. If I take this term out the two methods give the same answer.

I then tried two methods to improve my answer, one was dividing `b` by 1000 then dividing the sum by 1000 at the end. This didn't work, presumably because the float precision is the same either way.

I also tried forcing my `b` vector to be integers, which also didn't work.

Sample data doesn't reproduce my error either, which is frustrating...

```
objmat = rbind(rep(c(1,0,0),1000),rep(c(0,0,1),1000))
amat = rbind(rep(c(0.064384654, 0.025465132, 0.36543214),1000))
bmat = rbind(rep(c(1016.460431,1021.210431,1033.330431),1000))
ans = apply(objmat,1,function(x) sum((x-amat)/bmat))
```

gives

> ans[1] = 0.5418828413

> rowsums((objmat[1,]-amat)/bmat) = 0.5418828413

I think it has to be a floating point precision error, but I'm not sure why my dummy data doesn't reproduce it, or which method (`apply` or `rowsums`) would be more accurate!

Comment: What is `a` and `b`.  It may depend on the length of 'a' and 'b', In the `apply` you are looping over rows and I am assuming that a and b length will be the length of number of columns of the object.

Comment: Maybe none of the methods is throwing away precision or making rounding errors: `(1/5 + 3/5) - 4/5 == 1/5 + (3/5 - 4/5)`. This might be R [FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f) or [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal).

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? We don't need your (large) `object`, a small one would work just fine. I'm inferring the differences are sub-decimal, in which case one might use `runif` or another random function to generate it; if so, please remember to use `set.seed` so that we can see the same numbers/results. Thanks.

Comment: This post contains inadequate information to diagnose the issue beyond speculation that it is due to the normal rounding that occurs in floating-point operations. It does not even show an example of two different answers, let alone the inputs and actual code that produce them.

Comment: I get that! I'm working with some loaded data, but when I try to using dummy data to reproduce that error I can't, so speculation is all that I was hoping for!